# HDF5: How to decode UTF8-encoded string from h5dump output?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, hdf5, decoding

I'm writing an attribute to an HDF5 file using UTF-8 encoding. As an example, I've written "äöüß" to the attribute "notes" in the file.

I'm now trying to parse the output of `h5ls` (or `h5dump`) to extract this data back. Either tool gives me an output like this:

```
ATTRIBUTE "notes" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
         STRSIZE 8;
         STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
         CSET H5T_CSET_UTF8;
         CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
      }
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 1 ) / ( 1 ) }
      DATA {
      (0): "\37777777703\37777777644\37777777703\37777777666\37777777703\37777777674\37777777703\37777777637"
      }
   }
```

I'm aware that, e.g., `\37777777703\37777777644` *somehow* encodes `ä` as `0xC3 0xA4`, however, I have a really hard time coming up with *how* this encoding works.

**What's the magic formula behind this and how can I properly decode it back into `äöüß`?**

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, add a language tag and share code snippet where you create your file… BTW, `[0o37777777703 & 0o377, 0o37777777644 & 0o377] == [0xc3, 0xa4]` is `True` in Python…

Comment: I'm not sure what part of my example is not reproducible. Anyways, thanks for your mentioning of the octal interpretation. I wasn't aware that it's base 8 encoded, that pretty much solves it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The strings are encoded using base 8. I've decoded them in the PHP backend using:

```php
$line = "This is the text including some UTF-8 bytes \37777777703\37777777644\37777777703\37777777666\37777777703\37777777674\37777777703\37777777637";

// extract UTF-8 Bytes
$octbytes;
preg_match_all("/\\\\37777777(\\d{3})/", $line, $octbytes);

// parse extracted Bytes
for ($m = 0; $m < count($octbytes[1]); ) {
    $B = octdec($octbytes[1][$m]);

    // UTF-8 may span over 2 to 4 Bytes
    $numBytes;
    if (($B & 0xF8) == 0xF0) { $numBytes = 4; } 
    else if (($B & 0xF0) == 0xE0) { $numBytes = 3; } 
    else if (($B & 0xE0) == 0xC0) { $numBytes = 2; } 
    else { $numBytes = 1; }
                            
    $hxstr = "";
    $replaceStr = "";
    for ($j = 0; $j < $numBytes; $j++) {
        $match =  $octbytes[1][$m+$j];
        $dec = octdec($match) & 255;
        $hx = strtoupper(dechex($dec));
        $hxstr = $hxstr . $hx;
        $replaceStr = $replaceStr . "\\37777777" . $match;
    }

    // pack extracted bytes into one hex string
    $utfChar = pack("H*", $hxstr); // < this will be interpreted correctly
    
    // replace Bytes in the input with the parsed chars
    $parsedData = str_replace($replaceStr,$utfChar,$line);

    // go to next byte                            
    $m+=$numBytes;
}
echo "The parsed line: $line";
```